# ERROR: One or more files referenced by .inf file cannot be found in the package (wix)

Tags: wix, driver, wix3.6

I have created a wix installation project for an inf driver that outputs an msi. I have included the cat, sys and inf files as components shown below. When I run the msi it stops prematurely and the log file shows this error:

ERROR: One or more files referenced by .inf file cannot be found in the package.

I'm building it for 64 bit (for now) and have added the reference to difxapp_64. Can all inf files be packaged into an msi or is something else needed?

The main wxs:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
 xmlns:difx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/DifxAppExtension"
 xmlns:util='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension'>

<?if $(var.Platform)=x64 ?>
<?define ProductCode="{938775bb-4577-453d-8373-f03869bd2f37}" ?>
<?else?>
<?define ProductCode="{9e5fa76f-c865-4956-8651-f864dd5536f3}" ?>
<?endif?>
<?define ProductUpgradeCode = "5677d653-cc0d-4473-8ad4-89c8910524a5"?>

<Product
    Id="$(var.ProductCode)"
    Name="!(loc.ProductName_$(var.Platform))" 
    Manufacturer="!(loc.CompanyName)" 
    Version="0.0.1.0"
    Language="1033"
    UpgradeCode="$(var.ProductUpgradeCode)"
    >
    <Package 
        Manufacturer="!(loc.CompanyName)" 
        Description="!(loc.ProductName_$(var.Platform)) Installer" 
        Compressed="yes" 
        InstallerVersion="200"
        Platform="$(var.Platform)"
        InstallPrivileges='elevated'
        InstallScope='perMachine'/>
     <?include Settings.wxi ?>
        <Property Id="DiskPrompt" Value="!(loc.ProductName_$(var.Platform)) Installation" />
             <Property Id="ARPCONTACT" Value="!(loc.CompanyName)" />
             <Property Id="ARPURLINFOABOUT" Value="https://www.sitename.com" />
             <Property Id="ARPCOMMENTS">
                 !(loc.CompanyName) - !(loc.ProductName_$(var.Platform))
             </Property>
    
        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="!(loc.DowngradeErrorMessage)"/>
    
        <Media Id='1' Cabinet='Drivers.cab' EmbedCab='yes' DiskPrompt='DirFilter Media' />

    <Feature Id='ProductFeature' Title='Drivers' Level='1'>
        <ComponentGroupRef Id='ProductComponents' />
    </Feature>
        <Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLDIR" />
                <UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir" />
                <UI>
                    <Publish 
                        Dialog="WelcomeDlg" 
                        Control="Next"
                        Event="NewDialog" 
                        Value="InstallDirDlg" 
                        Order="5">1</Publish>
                    <Publish 
                        Dialog="InstallDirDlg"
                        Control="Back"
                        Event="NewDialog"
                        Value="WelcomeDlg"
                        Order="5">1</Publish>
                </UI>
    </Product>
</Wix>
```

Directories wxs:

```
<Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <?if $(var.Platform)=x64 ?>
            <Directory Id="ProgramFiles64Folder">
                <Directory Id="Company" Name="!(loc.CompanyName)">
                    <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="!(loc.ProductShortName)" />
                </Directory>
            </Directory>
        <?else?>
            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
                <Directory Id="Company" Name="!(loc.CompanyName)">
                    <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="!(loc.ProductShortName)" />
                </Directory>
            </Directory>
        <?endif?>
    </Directory>
</Fragment>
```

Components wxs:

```
<Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLDIR">
        <ComponentRef Id='sttube_Win10_64' />
    </ComponentGroup>

    <DirectoryRef Id='INSTALLDIR'>
        <Component Id="sttube_Win10_64" Guid="cd92a990-1783-477f-87c9-9da93a5c14ac" Win64="yes" 
             DiskId="1"  >
            <File Id="sttube.cat_Win10_64" Source="Driver\Win10\" Name="sttube.cat" />
            <File Id="STtube.inf_Win10_64" Source="Driver\Win10\" Name="STtube.inf"  />
            <File Id="STTub30.sys_Win10_64" Source="Driver\Win10\x64\" Name="STTub30.sys" 
               KeyPath="yes" />
            <difx:Driver AddRemovePrograms="yes" PlugAndPlayPrompt="no" Sequence='1' />
        </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>
</Fragment>
```

Comment: Can we see the content of the inf file? Is the STTub30.sys file perhaps supposed to be in an x64 sub-folder? Right clicking the Inf file and selecting Install works?

Comment: `DifxApp` has been [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/difx-guidelines). Yes, I know that WiX doesn't have a solution yet that uses the suggested replacement APIs.